# Handlings multiple hyperlink in an object in jsf datatable

Tags: java, jsf, hyperlink

I have this situation were I need to have two display multiple hyperlink present in a single object.

The code is as below

```
public HashMap<String, RowData> createRowDataIndexFromTuple(HashMap<String, String> row,
        DbTableTupleDataSetManager manager, HashMap<String, String> ermObjectPrimaryNameMap,
        HashMap<String, String> ermWithDateDataFormatMap, String sqlQuery) throws IllegalDataSetStructureException {
      HashMap<String, RowData> index = new HashMap<String, RowData>();
      boolean columnHyperlink = Boolean.FALSE;

      for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : row.entrySet()) {
          String columnName = entry.getKey();
          String changeTypeString = row.get(DataStoreUtils.CHANGE_TYPE_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_NAME);
          String data = entry.getValue();
          columnHyperlink = Boolean.FALSE;
          String dataColor = ""; 
          String orgData = "";
          String value="https://";
          String delimitor=",";
          String delimitor1="\\n";
          String tempData="";
          String destinationString1="";
         // final String lineSplit = System.getProperty("line.separator");

          if (columnName.contains(Crdutil.getMDMConstants().get("HYPERLINK_COLUMN_CONSTANT_NAME"))
              || columnName.contains(Crdutil.getMDMConstants().get("HYPERLINK_COLUMN_CONSTANT_NAME")))
          {
            columnHyperlink = Boolean.TRUE;


           if(null != data){

             StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(data, delimitor);//split the string into individual url's
              ArrayList<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
              String destinationString="\n";

              while (token.hasMoreTokens()) {

                  tokens.add(token.nextToken()); //create array list of url's
              }

              //check each url whether has http,https,ftp as part of web address,if not append it with https
            for (int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++) {

                tempData = tokens.get(i);
                if (tokens.get(i) != null
                        && !tokens.get(i).isEmpty()
                        && !"http".equalsIgnoreCase(tokens.get(i)
                                .toString().substring(0, 4))
                        && !"ftp".equalsIgnoreCase(tokens.get(i)
                                .toString().substring(0, 3))
                        && !"https".equalsIgnoreCase(tokens.get(i)
                                .toString().substring(0, 5))) {
                    tempData = value.concat(tokens.get(i)
                            .toString());

                                    //if there are more than one url,then club all url's delimited with a comma and display it as a single column value
                          if(i>=1)
                              destinationString=(destinationString+delimitor+(tempData)).replace(",", "\n");


                            //destinationString=String.format(destinationString+delimitor1,tempData);
                          else
                              destinationString=tempData;
                        } else
                            destinationString = tempData;

                    }
                  data=destinationString;

          }
          }
```

this is my jsf

```
     <c:dataTable  id="tupletable"  value="#{ciefEditor.dataView.filteredRows}" var="row" headerText="false" >

    <j:forEach var="typeName" items="#{ciefEditor.dataView.typeNames}">

      <rich:column id="col-${typeName}" width="" sortBy="#{row.rowDataIndex[typeName].sortColunmData}">
        <f:facet name="header">
          <h:outputText class="nobr" id="header-${typeName}" value="#{ciefEditor.dataView.header[typeName]}"  />
        </f:facet>
        <htm:font id="font-${typeName}" styleClass="#{row.rowDataIndex[typeName].dataColor}">          
          <h:outputText id="data-${typeName}" value="#{row.rowDataIndex[typeName].displayData}" rendered="#{!row.rowDataIndex[typeName].columnHyperlink}"
          title="#{row.rowDataIndex[typeName].displayData}" escape="#{row.rowDataIndex[typeName].escapeRequired}"/>

          <c:outputLink target = "_blank" 
            value="#{row.rowDataIndex[typeName].displayData}"
            rendered="#{row.rowDataIndex[typeName].columnHyperlink}">
            <c:outputText target = "_blank" 
            value="#{row.rowDataIndex[typeName].displayData}" 
            rendered="#{row.rowDataIndex[typeName].columnHyperlink}"
            title="#{row.rowDataIndex[typeName].displayData}" 
            escape="#{row.rowDataIndex[typeName].escapeRequired}"/>
      </c:outputLink>
        </htm:font>
      </rich:column>
    </j:forEach>
  </c:dataTable>
```

when there are more than one hyperlink like for ex:www.google.com,www.yahoo.com.
the hyperlink comes as a single url.so when clicked the browser url becomes something like www.google.comwww.yahoo.com.
Any help on this as am new to JSf

Comment: The solution is pretty simple... why dont you consider adding &nbsp; after c:outputlink ?

Comment: Hi madhura..I tried adding &nbsp; after c:outputlink.but it didn solve the issue :(